# How can pass for loop results into sklearns t test method

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, statsmodels, sklearn-pandas

I have a `for` loop that iterates over a list of machine learning algorithms, and I want to perform a T Test on the results of the machine learning models.

```
import pandas
import numpy
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_recall_curve, average_precision_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind, ttest_ind_from_stats
from scipy.special import stdtr
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import warnings

#Load KDD dataset
data_set =  "NSL-KDD/KDDTest+.arff"

print "Loading: ", data_set

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

names = ['duration','protocol_type','service','flag','src_bytes','dst_bytes','land','wrong_fragment','urgent','hot','num_failed_logins','logged_in','num_compromised','su_attempted','num_root','num_file_creations',
'num_shells','num_access_files','num_outbound_cmds','is_host_login','is_guest_login','count','srv_count','serror_rate','srv_serror_rate','rerror_rate','srv_rerror_rate','same_srv_rate','diff_srv_rate','srv_diff_host_rate',
'dst_host_count','dst_host_srv_count','dst_host_same_srv_rate','dst_host_diff_srv_rate','dst_host_same_src_port_rate','dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate','dst_host_serror_rate','dst_host_srv_serror_rate','dst_host_rerror_rate','class',
'dst_host_srv_rerror_rate']

dataset = pandas.read_csv(data_set, names=names)

for column in dataset.columns:
    if dataset[column].dtype == type(object):
        le = LabelEncoder()
        dataset[column] = le.fit_transform(dataset[column])

# split data into X and y -- these values must be changed to 8 for the diabites dataset and 4 for the iris dataset.
array = dataset.values
X = array[:,0:40]
Y = array[:,40]

# Split-out validation dataset
validation_size = 0.20
seed = 7
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)

# Test options and evaluation metric
num_folds = 7
num_instances = len(X_train)
seed = 7
scoring = 'accuracy'

#  Algorithms
models = []
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier())) 
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('Random Forest', RandomForestClassifier()))
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression()))

# **evaluate each model in turn and perform T Test here**
results = []
names = []
for name, model in models:
        kfold = cross_validation.KFold(n=num_instances, n_folds=num_folds, random_state=seed)
        cv_results = cross_validation.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
        results.append(cv_results)
        names.append(name)
        msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean()*100, cv_results.std()*100)#multiplying by 100 to show percentage
        print(msg)
        print cv_results*100
        #t, p = ttest_ind(cv_results, cv_results, equal_var=False)
        #print("T_Test: T Value = %g  P Value = %g" % (t, p))
```

Above is my for loop that iterates of the `models` list of algorithms,  which creates results which look like so:

`KNN: 90.027688 (0.269979)
[ 90.0464756   90.12393493  89.5817196   90.08136381  90.35257652
  89.69391709  90.31383185]
LDA: 83.646949 (0.187389)
[ 83.46243222  83.50116189  83.61735089  84.07593956  83.64974816
  83.57225881  83.64974816]
CART: 92.440512 (0.438941)
[ 92.79628195  92.52517428  91.94422928  93.02595893  92.59976753
  91.66989539  92.52227819]
NB: 29.662505 (1.702733)
[ 28.11773819  30.51897754  28.89233153  28.51607904  33.39790779
  29.67841922  28.51607904]
Random Forest: 92.318760 (0.355462)
[ 92.52517428  92.64136328  91.78931061  92.32855482  92.71600155
  91.78612941  92.44478884]`

**My question is**, How can I pass `cv_results` into the t test values `a, b`? as I have tried to directly pass in `cv_resutls` which produces the same resutls for each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the same t-statistic because you tested two identical arrays in each loop, that is a and b are both cv_results.
If you want to t-test between models, you can simply save all models' cv_results into a list, then loop over this list to compute pairwise t-test.

E.g.:

```
for i in range(len(results) - 1):
    for j in range(i, len(results)):
        t, p = ttest_ind(results[i], results[j], equal_var=False)
        print("T_Test between {} & {}: T Value = {}, P Value = {}".format(names[i], names[j], t, p))
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks.